# ¿Por qué "manzanar" lleva la -r?

Tags: etimología, plantas

El sitio en que crece una planta fructífera normalmente tiene nombre que termina en -l, como *duraznal*, *moral*, y *naranjal*. En cuanto a los manzanos, existe *manzanal* pero parece más común la forma *manzanar*. Ya que las definiciones de la DRAE y el Wikcionario no lo discuten, ¿por qué esa palabra adquirió la forma distinta?

Comment: Es bien posible que la forma verdadera es *-r*, pero por causa de tener dos /r/ una se convirtió en /l/ (un proceso bien sabido, por ejemplo, *local* --> *lugar*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

También tienes *pinar*, *melonar* y otros que acaban en *-r*. En el diccionario aparecen las dos terminaciones:

> **[-al](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1PYY1SR)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. -ālis.
> ```
>
> 1. suf. En adjetivos, indica generalmente relación o pertenencia. *Ferrovial, cultural.*
> 2. suf. En sustantivos, indica el lugar en que abunda el primitivo. *Arrozal, peñascal.*
>
> ---
>
> [**-ar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3NNxyGS)
>
> ```
> Del lat. -āris.
> ```
>
> 1. suf. En los adjetivos significa condición o pertenencia. *Espectacular, axilar.*
> 2. suf. En los sustantivos indica el lugar en que abunda el primitivo. *Pinar, palomar.*

Las acepciones que nos interesan son las segundas de cada caso, y como puedes ver ambas terminaciones provienen de sendas terminaciones que ya existían en latín: *-ālis* y *-āris*, luego esta diferenciación ya existía en dicho idioma. He preguntado [en el sitio de latín](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7615/2646) si había alguna diferencia entre ambos sufijos por entonces o si había alguna regla que aplicara para usar uno u otro. Hay que tener en cuenta que *[manzana](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OItjStD)* como tal no existía en latín clásico, dado que proviene de *Mattiana mala*, literalmente "manzanas de Matio" en honor a C. Mattius.

En todo caso, parece que el caso de *manzanar* es curioso. En el *Diccionario de autoridades* se recogen ambas:

> MANZANAL ò MANZANAR. s. m. El sítio plantado de manzánas.

Y cita como ejemplo precisamente un caso con *l*:

> Y pidiéronle mercéd, que las sus gentes no les hiciessen mal en los peráles, ni en los panes ni en los *manzanáles*.

No hay muchos casos en el CORDE, pero *manzanar* aparece en el siglo X:

> *Et ipsa ecclesia Sancti Mikaeli cum suas casas, et ipsa hereditate tota cum suis pumiferis et suos manzanares et ortules, cum terris, vineis, molinis, pratis, pascuis, cum exitus et regressus, ab omni integritate.*
>
> Anónimo, "De Monte Aurio [Becerro gótico de Cardeña]", 968 (España).

Y *manzanal* aparece algo después:

> *... hes a sauer nonbradamente la cassa e lagar e el molino e los manzanales e la naza, dejando la terçia parte del agua a la uilla franco e quito...*
>
> Anónimo, "Carta de concierto", 1299 (España).

Así pues parece ser que ambas formas convivieron y que no fue hasta tiempos más recientes que ha parecido asentarse más en el idioma la forma con *r*.